# For WiFi Easy connect or Enhanced Open to support on my android device what are the hardware requirements?

Tags: android, wifi

To support this features , are there any changes require in hardware or firmware?

Comment: Please add some references about what is `WiFi Easy connect` and `Enhanced Open`

Comment: This features are coming along with android Q. You can look into it here.https://www.wi-fi.org/discover-wi-fi/wi-fi-easy-connect and here https://www.wi-fi.org/news-events/newsroom/wi-fi-certified-enhanced-open-delivers-data-protection-in-open-wi-fi-networks

Answer (score 0):

Wifi easy connect (DPP-Device Provisioning Protocol) and Enhanced Open (OWE) need wifi vendor's support. It might not be implemented in wifi HW, but in the wifi driver with/without FW patch, depends on wifi vendor design.

Most relative functions are implemented in wpa_supplicant, which is the application in user space. And the wifi driver needs to report the data, received from AP to wpa_supplicant, and transmit the correct data generated from wpa_supplicant to AP,  by using kernel cfg80211 functions.

1. wifi easy connect
   need to handle public action frame
2. OWE (Opportunistic Wireless Encryption OWE)
   PMK is generated by association handshaking. 
   so the wifi driver needs to use e.g. cfg80211_connect_result() to report association response ie to the wpa_supplicant